# Spring rest web service controller not able to return List object

Tags: java, spring, list, rest, controller

Thanks for looking into the issue i am facing and for your response.

Issue --> Spring rest controller not able to return List object.While making request from rest client browser extension I am not getting any errors but i can only see waiting animation icon and no response.I waited for few minutes then aborted the request,did this multiple time.Checked logs and based on it observed that response is coming till controller seems something to do with the return statement in controller.

Code as follows :-

Spring rest controller :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import com.wells.exptrack.constants.Result;
import com.wells.exptrack.service.UserService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/service")
public class EmployeeController {
@Autowired
UserService userService;
@RequestMapping(value="/get/all/News/user/{empId}", method=RequestMethod.GET,consumes = {"application/json"}, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Result getAllNews(@PathVariable("empId") int eId) {        
    return userService.getAllNews(eId);
    }   }
```

service class as follows:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Result getAllNews(int empId) {                       
com.myorg.myproj.entities.Employee employeeEntity = userDao.getEmpById(empId);  
List cards= employeeEntity.getCards();   
com.myorg.myproj.entities.Card cardEntity = (Card) cards.get(0);        
List allNews = cardEntity.getNews();                
Result result = new Result();   
NewsPayload tran = new NewsPayload();
tran.setNewsList(allNews);
result.setPayload(tran);
return result;
}
```

Other supporting classes :

```
public class Result {   
private int code;
private String description;
private Payload payload;    
public int getCode() {
    return code;
}
public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
}
public Payload getPayload() {
    return payload;
}
public void setPayload(Payload payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}


public class NewsPayload implements Payload{
private int empId;
public List getNewsList() {
    return newsList;
}
public void setNewsList(List newsList) {
    this.newsList = newsList;
}
private  List newsList = new ArrayList();
public int getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}
public void setEmpId(int empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide the whole source code for the controller

Comment: What is `commons`? Also, you don't need to create a new arraylist just to call `employeeEntity.getCards();` afterwards and overwrite the first list.

Comment: Hi dambros/Abdelillah, updated the code as per your convenience, We can do this without common class as its just an add on. Thanks